# Dax Studio - The syntax for Calculate is incorrect

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I am learning to use DAX Studio to test out my DAX scripts,

DAX Studio says my script is wrong, but I am not sure what exactly is the problem

```
CummulativeWeek =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Data[Value] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( Data[Week] ), Data[Week] <= MAX ( Data[Week] ) ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( Data[Year] ), Data[Year] == MAX ( Data[Year] ) )
)
```

[image]

I don't see what I am doing wrong. I checked the docummentation, YouTube vids, everything seems to be fine.

In PowerBI the command is executed just fine.

[image]

Is there a setting in DAX Studio that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the EVALUATE keyword?

Also, you need to return a table.

Have a read here: https://daxstudio.org/docs/tutorials/writing-dax-queries/

Comment: I see. I thought the problem was there was something wrong with the CALCULATE command. Turns out DAX Studio does things different. Thanks!